# жизнь access_token

Tags: php, symfony

при попытке oauth токен живет меньше минуты,

```
$tokenParams = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://personal-vk-account.ru/vk_in',
    'code' => $request->get('code'),
];
```

вывдает ошибку после обновления страницы

```
Client error: `GET https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpersonal-vk-account.ru%2Fvk_in&code=409b30dbdaac88faaf` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code is invalid or expired."}
```

нигде не могу найти как изменить время жизни

Answer (score 1):

Для получения токена на большой срок в VK надо передать в запрос в секцию scopes "offline" , вот это сказано в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/permissions)

Для большего понимания можно посмотреть или использовать официальный [SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-php-sdk).

Comment: $tokenParams = [
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://personal-vk-account.ru/vk_in',
            'code' => $request->get('code'),
            'scopes' => 'offline'
        ];

Comment: добавила, ничего не изменилось

Comment: ошибка Code is invalid or expired. 
может дело не в токене